# Oracle: Analytics: How to Sort Using Some Column Names

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, oracle11g, analytics

I have a query same as below.

```
select organization_name, is_manager, is_vendor, is_engineer
from table_org_roles;
```

Example data:

```
organization_name|is_manager|is_vendor|is_engineer
---------------------------------------------------
Org_A            |Yes       |No       |No         
Org_B            |No        |Yes      |No         
Org_C            |No        |No       |Yes
Org_D            |Yes       |No       |Yes
```

However I wanted to make a SQL query that will be ordered by the the role name ascended which is the column name. How can I make query that will display like below:

```
Roles(ASC) | Organization
-------------------------
is_engineer| Org_C
is_engineer| Org_D
is_manager | Org_A
is_manager | Org_D
is_vendor  | Org_B
```

Is it possible to make such query using Analytics?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is it possible a manager is also a engineer?

Comment: Hi jarlh, yes it can be done with the table structure. Thank you

Comment: @Jemry, so if ORG_D is both manager and engineer, what's the expected output?

Comment: Hi jarlh, I have updated my question in the case you said. Thank you for asking.

Comment: Great, it looks like Jens' answer below will work here too. (But you can switch to UNION ALL, since no duplicate elimination is required.) BTW, is that Oracle specific case syntax, or is the keyword CASE missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this can be done with the help of an UNPIVOT operation as well. see below.

```
   create table test_stack
(
organization_name varchar2(100),
is_manager varchar2(10),
is_vendor varchar2(20),
is_engineer varchar2(20)
);
/
insert into test_stack
select 'org_A','Yes','No','No' from dual
union all
select 'org_B','No','Yes','No' from dual
union all
select 'org_C','No','No','Yes' from dual
union all
select 'org_D','Yes','No','Yes' from dual; 




select organization_name,roles
    from test_stack
    unpivot include nulls ( existence for Roles in ( IS_MANAGER as 'IS_MANAGER',IS_VENDOR as 'IS_VENDOR',IS_ENGINEER as 'IS_ENGINEER'))
    where existence ='Yes';
```

Comment: Hi Asfakul Islam, thank you, your answer is interesting. I tried it but I'm getting "ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here" because my actual SQL uses two tables: From TableA, TableB. Then in my column IS_MANAGER, i have TableA.IS_MANAGER. That's why I'm getting the error. Would appreciate if you have also advice how to handle this error in using pivot. I'm still searching the net also. Thank you.

Comment: @Jemru  Hi Jemru, Sorry I was away for sometime. Have you got your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this untested query:

```
select  * (
select organization_name, is_manager case is_manager WHEN Yes THEN "is_manager" ELSE "" END As Roles from  table_org_roles where is_manager = "YES"
union all
select organization_name, is_engineer case is_engineer WHEN Yes THEN "is_engineer " ELSE "" END from  table_org_roles where is_engineer= "YES"
union all
select organization_name, is_vendor case is_vendor WHEN Yes THEN "is_vendor" ELSE "" END from  table_org_roles where is_vendor= "YES"
) order by Roles
```

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your solution, it helped me! But I just used "UNION" to avoid duplication. Thanks.